# Android OnEditorActionListener id always zero

Tags: android, android-edittext

The action id is always zero, no matter what I change.

Java:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "+++ FFS %d", actionId);
        return false;
    }
});
```

XML:

```
 <EditText
        ...
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionLabel="Custom" />
```

Or:

```
 <EditText
        ...
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/new_action"
        android:imeActionLabel="Custom" />
```

Or `actionSend` for imeOptions as well. Does it just not work whatsoever?

Setting it in Java (either in addition to or instead of the XML setting) also has no effect.

Comment: I had to explicitly do this before it would work for me:  someEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

Comment: @Martin still it is zero even if I set it in Java as well as XML.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

```
android:inputType="text"
```

For the IME Action to take effect